# при загрузке фото с помощю requests пишет 'Недействительное изображение'

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

я написал парсер, который буде закачивать опридиленные картинки на сайте, но почему-то, когда я захожу в картинку мне пишет 'Недействительное изображение'. Раньше исправлял это используя другой юзер-агент, но сейчас это не помогает.
код парсера:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import os
import time

number = input(">>> ")

title_name = "Sweet Home"

if not os.path.exists(title_name):
    os.mkdir(title_name)

if not os.path.exists(f"{title_name}/chapter {number}"):
    os.mkdir(f"{title_name}/chapter {number}")

service = Service("C:/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)
driver.get(f"https://mangaweebs.in/manga/sweet-home/chapter-{number}/")

time.sleep(10)

images = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wp-manga-chapter-img')

for image in images:
    image_src = image.get_attribute("src")
    print(image_src)
    image_num = image.get_attribute("id").split('-')
    print(image_num)

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/"
    }

    response = requests.get(image_src, stream=True, headers=headers)


    with open(f"{title_name}/chapter {number}/{number}_{image_num[1]}.jpg", 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

также, мне дает ошибку от самого парсера:

```
[1792:1984:1027/200955.100:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
```

Comment: Зачем селениум для простой закачки изображения?

Comment: там js подгружает картинки

Comment: Дайте ссылку и скажите какие вам картинки нужны... 100% можно вытащить более лёгким и быстрым способом

Comment: парсер нужен для загрузки манги. Сам сайт: https://mangaweebs.in/manga/sweet-home/chapter-33/

Comment: Ну так и в чём проблема? ссылка строится как то так: `https://cdn.mangaweebs.in/data_2/manga_610783a4912ff/chapter-1/001.jpg`

Comment: Да и картинки подгружаются не через js, а через html

Comment: хмм, почему-то я подумал что через js. Я то понимаю что ссылка так строиться и програма картинки отлично загружает. Но когда я захожу в картинку мне пишет 'Недействительное изображение'.

Comment: Что там недействительного, если эта ссылка даже в браузере открывается? Просто загружайте изображения пока не получите ошибку 404

Comment: на первом же фото дало 403 статус-код. поэтому не загружало. Не знаете почему и как это исправить?

Comment: Не знаю. Вот мои заголовки, попробуйте их https://pastebin.com/j89kqjwJ

Comment: все равно 403 при вот таком коде:
```import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.69",
    "Referer": "https://www.google.com/"
}

response = requests.get("https://cdn.mangaweebs.in/data_2/manga_610783a4912ff/chapter-33/104.jpg", stream=True, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("C:/image.jpg", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
else:
    print(f"{response.status_code}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;'
                         ' rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0'}
number = 33
title_name = "Sweet Home"
path_number = f"{title_name}/chapter {number}"
if not os.path.exists(title_name):
    os.mkdir(title_name)
if not os.path.exists(path_number):
    os.mkdir(path_number)

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update(headers)
url = f'https://mangaweebs.in/manga/sweet-home/chapter-{number}'
response = sess.get(url)
if not response.ok:
    print(f"{response.status_code}", url)
    exit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
img = (x['src'].strip() for x in soup(class_="wp-manga-chapter-img"))

for index, url_img in enumerate(img, 1):
    response = sess.get(url_img)
    if not response.ok:
        print(f"{response.status_code}", url)
        continue
    with Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) as webp_image:
        webp_image.save(f"{path_number}/{number}_{index:03d}.jpg", "JPEG")
```